# iMacros and socket.io

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, imacros

In my iMacros script I try to connect to a server using socket.io. 
First I have to obtain the socket.io.js file, evaluate it and then use socket.io as normal. 
Here is an excerpt from my script:

```
    function loadScriptFromURL(url) {
        try {
            var request = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
            request.open('GET', url, false);
            request.send();
            if (request.status !== 200) {
                var message = 'There was an error trying to connect to: ' + url + ', request status: ' + request.status;
                iimDisplay(message);
            }
            eval(request.response);
        } catch (e) {
            window.console.log(e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        //alert(request.respsonse);
    }

    loadScriptFromURL('http://localhost:3700/socket.io/socket.io.js');
    window.console.log(io.version); // returns 0.9.16
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3700');
```

The problem is that a Javascript code that is executed by iMacros is in the scope of the plugin (a sandbox), and when I use the io's connect method I get the "io.util is undefined" error. 
Is there a way to populate this method so that iMacros could see it? I guess I need to make some changes in the socket.io.js file, but not quite sure yet...

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple of days to find a solution. I have another errors, for example "setTimeout() is not a function, Blob is not a function, diferent undefined errors..."
This occurs because the code is not running in the context of the current window.

Solution:

Go to "/node_modules/socket.io-client\socket.io.js"

It's client javascript code from url "http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"

Replace all:

```
"new Blob" -> "new window.Blob"
"instanceof Blob" -> "instanceof window.Blob"

And to do the same for:
Filereader - > window.Filereader
setTimeout() - > window.setTimeout()
clearTimeout() - > window.clearTimeout()
setTimeout() - > window.setTimeout()
```

It's working for me. Node.JS version is 5.3.0, Socket.IO version is 1.4.5.